# Why is this Java code not printing Long values?

Tags: java, long-integer

I wrote a simple Stopwatch class as follows.

```
public class StopWatch 
{
  private long startTime;
  private long stopTime;
  private boolean isRunning;


  public void Start()
 {
this.startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
this.isRunning=true;

 }

 public void Stop()
 {
this.stopTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
this.isRunning=false;

 }


public long timeElapsed()
{
if(isRunning)
{
    return ((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

}
else
{
    return ((stopTime-startTime));
}



 }
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
StopWatch s=new StopWatch();
try
{
s.Start();
int sum=0;
for( int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{

sum=sum+i;  

}
s.Stop();
long timetaken=s.timeElapsed();
System.out.println(timetaken);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
 }  




  }
```

If I add +100L to stop time then I get answer as 100. For some reason both starttime and stoptime have the same value and the subtraction is 0. Not sure why that is happening.

I had also put 100000 as the loop counter and even that had given me 0. While copy pasting code the value was 10 in for loop.

With nanoseconds it's working fine, I was trying to check for performance issues that come with autoboxing in Java.

Comment: A typical loop like this takes about 1 ns per iteration or less.  Even with nanoTime() the loop doesn't run long enough to make a difference.  Note: the JVM is good at optimising code which doesn't do anything so you might find even with 1,000,000,000 iteration it won't take any time either.

Comment: Method names should not start with an uppercase letter. 'Start' and 'Stop' should be 'start' and 'stop'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for( int i=0;i<=10;i++) {  sum=sum+i;    }
```

The execution time of the above code is `less than a millisecond`. Try with `System.nanoTime()`

Comment: is must not be less than one millisecond, the system timer is not required to have that resolution. For Windows it normally is 16 milliseconds... (just a note, still +1)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: yes. In linux systems, it is usually 8 to 10ms and the timer is relying on the system interrupt resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe things are running too fast for the clock that currentTimeMillis is using ?
This function returns values in milliseconds, but I don't think that it is required that it has a resolution of milliseconds.

In fact: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
for( int i=0;i<=10;i++) {  
   sum=sum+i;    
}
```

executes in less than a milisecond :)

Use something like

```
for( int i=0;i<=10;i++) {  
   sum=sum+i;    
   Thread.sleep(100L);
}
```

to see a result, although I am not sure what is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both the time is same that is why it is returning 0.

Use this on the top of stop method and it will give u correct answer:

```
         try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, depending on your system, `System.currentTimeMillis()` doesn't necessarily actually count to the nearest millisecond.